# Regular expression adjustment not working as expected

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have the following regex https://regex101.com/r/arBFtI/2.

It is a regex for searching and replacing on a webpage. It searches and replaces the results by appending a highlight div so the words show up accordingly for the user.

In order to make sure the HTML itself is not changed (page can not break..) it recognizes HTML tags/attributes so it doesn't show a result in that.

But I have one more issue, now the regexp is strict and only shows a results if it is preceded with a space.

When searching for "**export**" it will show a result in the sentence above but not in the query below on `db0383_bpost.export_201506`.

In order to match on all "**export**" occurrences I can adjust the regex to be `(?<![&((])export(?![^<>]*(([\/\"']|]]|\b)>))` but then the following problem arises.. HTML entities!

If you search on "**b**" for example using `(?<![&((])b(?![^<>]*(([\/\"']|]]|\b)>))` it will also match the **b** in `&nbsp;` ..

So I like the "strict" regexp `(?<![&((\S+])export(?![^<>]*(([\/\"']|]]|\b)>))` or `(?<![&((\S+])b(?![^<>]*(([\/\"']|]]|\b)>))` when searching for b but the only thing I need is for it to ignore HTML entities as well. So if I search for "**b**" it should match all the **b**'s except in HTML entities and **b**'s not between HTML tags.

It looks like a slight adjustment to the original regex in the `(\S+])` part but I can't figure it out. Can you? Please help me I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is it in JavaScript?

Comment: Something is clearly wrong with at least this: `[&((\S+]` ... Are those `&` and `(` chars meant to be matched literally? Because at least for `((`, there is no point in having two inside the character set defined by `[ ]`...

Comment: It is Actionscript (AS3). I don't understand the regex myself since I did not write it.

Comment: I tried and came up with this: (?<![(&\w)(])export(?![^<>]*(([\/\"']|]]|\b)>))

Comment: Now (?<![(&\w)(])b(?![^<>]*(([\/\"']|]]|\b)>)) does not match in nbsp; so that seems to work, is this the correct approach?

Comment: Can't I run two regexp in one? Because the above regex does not work when searching for "Bed&Breakfast" , so I need a check on the ; of the HTML entities as well but I don't know if this can be done in one regex together with the other requirements..